# jQueryMobile loses fixed navbar when back button is used

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a fixed navbar in the footer that looks like this (except I have a header aswell):

http://brooky.cc/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/nav_icon.png

When I change page from the homepage, users get the back button in the header. The problem is when the back button is tapped, the entire footer navbar disappears. I want the navbar there at all times. This problem occurs on the iPhone, but my desktop browsers work no problem.

My page setup is seperate files (one page per file) so I have index.php and products.php which are currently identical except for the header changed. The code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<title>Page Title</title> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4.1/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="home">

<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Home</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <p>Home screen.</p>     

</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
    <div data-role="navbar">
        <ul id="footernav">
            <li><a href="index.php" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="top">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="products.php" data-icon="star" class="ui-btn-active" data-iconpos="top">Products</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!-- /navbar -->
</div>

</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've noticed some issues with tapping and my fixed footer that may help. Tap seems to bubble up to somewhere and move my fixed footer to the bottom of the document. The next tap brings it back to the bottom of the screen etc. Sometimes it isn't consistent. I've also noticed sometimes my home page upon opening doesn't have my nav bar and usually a tap brings it to the screen. Sometimes it takes a couple of taps.

Answer (score 0):

Chris, I fear that this is an unresolved issue, see

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/1047

Some folks have recommended IScroll, which you might want to check out.

http://cubiq.org/iscroll

I've had the same problem, but was able to use another workaround for my case, which might be too much overhead for your case.

In our project, we decided to use jQuery templating, so all content of a page is created dynamically. See

http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/

I registered a callback with the pageshow event, and then filled a template. This is pretty straightforward as described in the jQuery template documentation. With this technique, I was able to avoid the bug, but I think checking IScroll might be worthwhile for you unless you already use jQuery templates.